# Advanced query in Dapper

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, dapper

I have the following object structure in a c# object

```
new [] {
    new SomeType {
       Id = XXX,
       SomeSubType = new []{z,y,x,w}
    }, 
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I am trying to create something like the following sql query for Dapper.

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table, some_other_table
WHERE (X = XXX/*@Id*/ AND Y IN (z, y, x, w) /*@SomeSubType*/)
       OR (X = AND Y IN (....))
       OR (....)
       OR (....)
       ..... )
```

I could dynamically create the query, according to the object, and create a lot of parameters for each option - but that is a pain.

Can anyone think of a nicer way to do it? maybe a better query that makes sure both conditions are met?

Comment: May be you should read the flat list data (from your joins) and group them in C#

Comment: that is actually not a bad Idea, I think that is what I'll do.

Comment: I'd say dynamically creating the query is the best bet, but depending on the types of X and Y you could combine them like `X + ' ' + Y IN @Combined` and then `@Combined` would be `stuff.SelectMany(i => i.SomSubType.Select(j => i.X + " " + j.Y))`  But that could result in an inefficient query.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, however - my ids are int and converting it to a string might affect performance in a bad way - as for creating a dynamic query - it might be more expensive than @shyju's option

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is Dapper's SqlBuilder()?

https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/blob/master/Dapper.SqlBuilder/SqlBuilder.cs

[How do I build a dynamic sql query with Dapper.SqlBuilder and OrWhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37487201/how-do-i-build-a-dynamic-sql-query-with-dapper-sqlbuilder-and-orwhere)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correct you have a list of possible OR filters like this:

```cs
var filters = new SomeType[] {
    new SomeType { Id = ..., Subtypes = new []{z,y,x,w} }, 
    new SomeType { Id = ..., Subtypes = new []{z,y,x,w} }, 
    new SomeType { Id = ..., Subtypes = new []{z,y,x,w} }, ...
}
```

You can easily create that dynamic condition **using [DapperQueryBuilder](https://github.com/Drizin/DapperQueryBuilder/)**:

```cs
var query = cn.QueryBuilder($@"
    SELECT *
    FROM some_table, some_other_table
    /**where**/");

// by default multiple filters are combined with AND
query.FiltersType = Filters.FiltersType.OR; 

foreach (var filter in filters)
    query.Where($"X = {filter.Id} AND Y IN {filter.Subtypes}");

var results = query.Query<YourPOCO>();
```

Disclaimer: I'm one of the authors of this library